# Multiple MySQL queries in PHP, skipped

Tags: php, mysql

If I'm doing multiple MySQL queries on the same table, occasionally some get skipped.

Why is that?

For example:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'"); 
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field2` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'"); 
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field3` = '0' WHERE `Id` = '$something'");
?>
```

Sometimes one of the queries will not be executed?

Why is that?

Or is it something wrong with my server not general MySQL?

(Obviously I know now to update the same table in the same query, but before that I was confused as to why it happens, can anyone please explain?)

Comment: could you show us the code before and after the queries?

Comment: Try `mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());` for debugging purposes. I bet some of your querys are just failing silently. The PHP interpreter will generally not just skip statements and the MySQL DBS will not randomly ignore queries.

Comment: Try echoing `mysql_error()` after each query for debugging purposes. This will tell you if anything went wrong with the query

Comment: How can one of them fail though? They all have the same where clause. It's only one that fails every like 1,000 times randomly.

Comment: Are you escaping `$something` properly?

Comment: Yes, it's just a number and it's the same for all three queries so why would only one fail every now and then? :(

Comment: If it's just one in a thousand queries, there might be some issues with the database, like too many open connections or something with locks. You can have MySQL log errors: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to make 3 queries, if you are updating the same rows:

```
$q = "
    UPDATE table 
    SET field = '', 
        field2 = '',
        field3 = 0 
    WHERE Id = :id
";
$statement = $pdo->prepare( $q );
$statement->bindParam(':id', $something, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

Also, you should stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are not maintained anymore and process for deprecation has [already begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Maybe you should avoid the 10+ year old API and learn something for this decade: [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Old is not a bad thing when talking about librarys. Never touch a running system. The post that expresses the desire to remove ext/mysql is nearly two years old and I don't see that they even extended the documention with PDO examples.

Comment: @Basti: Old is a bad thing.  Remember that [Complacency Kills](http://mylifeblogs.com/2011/10/complacency-kills/)...  Remember what Einstein said: *The world is a dangerous place. Not because of the people who are evil; but because of the people who don’t do anything about it.*  So yes, old is a bad thing, and to say *Never touch a running system* is down right negligent.  Now, take precautions and don't just fiddle with it for no reason, but if there is a reason (which there is in this case), absolutely touch a running system...

Comment: I don't see how this is related to programming. Einstein lived in a time where no computers existed. I don't see C's string processing librarys getting switched every year. I'm not saying that one shouldn't switch to PDO or mysqli. But the reason is not that ext/mysql is getting worse each year, it's that PDO/mysqli are getting improved and stuffed with new features. Don't talk bad about ext/mysql. Instead advertise PDO/mysqli with features.

Comment: @Basti: actually, ext/mysql is getting worse each year.  It's not actively developed (new features are not supported), and it does not support the proper way of writing queries (Parameterized Queries - Prepared Statements).  So yes, it is worth replacing in your applications.  And saying that the quote is irrelevant because Einstein lived without computers (which is wrong) is a bit of a [Straw Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) argument.  And if that's all you took from what I wrote, I'd revisit it and think about it a bit...

Comment: Saying that something gets worse, because it does not get new features, is just wrong. It's simply the same as before. You can do what ext/mysql was developed for and nothing else. If you want modern features like prepared statements, go use PDO/mysqli. And yes, I did not read your article because I'm not interessted in philosophy, just plain old arguments.

Comment: @Basti here's one from someone from this generation ;] "Once a new technology rolls over you, if you're not part of the steamroller, you're part of the road." -Stewart Brand

Comment: @Carrie Good one! ;-) I'm off. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

debug your code to see if a query fails:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field2` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field3` = '0' WHERE `Id` = '$something'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to debug the code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field2` = '' WHERE `Id` = '$something'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("UPDATE `tb` SET `field3` = '0' WHERE `Id` = '$something'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE**

Make sure you are escaping `$something` using:

```
$something = mysql_real_escape_string($something);
```